# Calculating gradient of NN in pure python

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, neural-network, backpropagation

```py
import numpy

# Data and parameters

X  = numpy.array([[-1.086,  0.997,  0.283, -1.506]])
T  = numpy.array([[-0.579]])
W1 = numpy.array([[-0.339, -0.047,  0.746, -0.319, -0.222, -0.217],
                      [ 1.103,  1.093,  0.502,  0.193,  0.369,  0.745],
                      [-0.468,  0.588, -0.627, -0.319,  0.454, -0.714],
                      [-0.070, -0.431, -0.128, -1.399, -0.886, -0.350]])
W2 = numpy.array([[ 0.379, -0.071,  0.001,  0.281, -0.359,  0.116],
                      [-0.329, -0.705, -0.160,  0.234,  0.138, -0.005],
                      [ 0.977,  0.169,  0.400,  0.914, -0.528, -0.424],
                      [ 0.712, -0.326,  0.012,  0.437,  0.364,  0.716],
                      [ 0.611,  0.437, -0.315,  0.325,  0.128, -0.541],
                      [ 0.579,  0.330,  0.019, -0.095, -0.489,  0.081]])
W3 = numpy.array([[ 0.191, -0.339,  0.474, -0.448, -0.867,  0.424],
                      [-0.165, -0.051, -0.342, -0.656,  0.512, -0.281],
                      [ 0.678,  0.330, -0.128, -0.443, -0.299, -0.495],
                      [ 0.852,  0.067,  0.470, -0.517,  0.074,  0.481],
                      [-0.137,  0.421, -0.443, -0.557,  0.155, -0.155],
                      [ 0.262, -0.807,  0.291,  1.061, -0.010,  0.014]])
W4 = numpy.array([[ 0.073],
                      [-0.760],
                      [ 0.174],
                      [-0.655],
                      [-0.175],
                      [ 0.507]])
B1 = numpy.array([-0.760,  0.174, -0.655, -0.175,  0.507, -0.300])
B2 = numpy.array([ 0.205,  0.413,  0.114, -0.560, -0.136,  0.800])
B3 = numpy.array([-0.827, -0.113, -0.225,  0.049,  0.305,  0.657])
B4 = numpy.array([-0.270])

# Forward pass

Z1 = X.dot(W[0])+B[0]
A1 = numpy.maximum(0,Z1)
Z2 = A1.dot(W[1])+B[1]
A2 = numpy.maximum(0,Z2)
Z3 = A2.dot(W[2])+B[2]
A3 = numpy.maximum(0,Z3)
Y  = A3.dot(W[3])+B[3];

# Error

err = ((Y-T)**2).mean()
```

Given this example, I want to implement the backward pass, and obtain the gradient with respect to the weight and bias parameters. Apparently, the gradients for the last layer are given as follows:

```py
DY = 2*(Y-T)
DB4 = DY.mean(axis=0)
DW4 = A3.T.dot(DY) / len(X)
DZ3 = DY.dot(W4.T)*(Z3 > 0)
```

I do know that the different derivatives are calculated using the chain rule, but I don't quite understand how you come to this solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use the chain rule for (partial) derivatives and the rules of matrix differentiation, refer to the following figure showing the last hidden layer of the neural net for back-propagation of (MSE) error for regression:

[image]

> E = err = (Y - T)**2 (take mean over the batch to compute MSE)

> DY = ∂E/∂Y
> = 2 * (Y - T)

> ∂E/∂W3
> = (∂E/∂Y).(∂Y/∂W3)
> = DY. (∂/∂W3 (A3.W3+B3))
> = DY.A3.T
>
> = A3.T.DY
> (take mean over all training examples in training batch X: sum and divide by batch size |X|)

> ∂E/∂B3
> = (∂E/∂Y).(∂Y/∂B3)
> = DY. (∂/∂B3 (A3.W3+B3))
> = DY.1
>
> = DY (take mean over all the examples in a batch)

> ∂E/∂Z3
> = (∂E/∂Y).(∂Y/∂A3).(∂A3/∂Z3)
>
> = DY.(∂/∂A3 (A3.W3+B3)).(1.{Z3>0} + 0.{Z3 <= 0})
>
> = DY. W3.T. {Z3 > 0), where (.) is the indicator function. Using the
> definition of nonlinear RELU activation, the derivative is 1 when
> Z3>0, otherwise 0.

Answer (score 1):

For instance, `DY` is the derivative of `err` with respect to `Y`, so

```
d/dY (Y - T)**2 == 2 * (Y - T)
```

This is a plain old derivative, no chain rule yet.

Looks like DB4 is, using the chain rule:

```
d/dB[3] err == d/dB[3] (A3 @ W[3] + B[3] - T)**2
== 2 * (A3 @ W[3] + B[3] - T) * d/dB[3] (A3 @ W[3] + B[3] - T)
== 2 * (A3 @ W[3] + B[3] - T) * 1
== 2 * (Y - T)
== DY
```

DW4 is:

```
d/dW[3] err == d/dW[3] (A3 @ W[3] + B[3] - T)**2
== 2 * (A3 @ W[3] + B[3] - T) @ (d/dW[3] (A3 @ W[3] + B[3] - T))
== 2 * (Y - T) @ A3.T
[must match matrix shape]
== A3.T @ DY
```

The trick to `A3.T @ DY` is that `d/dW[3] (A3 @ W[3]) = A3.T`: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1866757/not-understanding-derivative-of-a-matrix-matrix-product.

To differentiate through `A3` when computing `DZ3 == d/dZ3 err`, one should take into account the activation function (TBH, I think `Y = A3.dot(W[3])+B[3]` should be `Y = numpy.maximum(0, A3.dot(W[3])+B[3])` because the final output should be the result of the activation function, but maybe your network architecture doesn't do that), which is [ReLU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifier_(neural_networks)) in your case.